# "Unable to retrieve API documentation" on admin of api-platform

Tags: admin-on-rest, api-platform.com

I trying to use all features of [api-platform](https://api-platform.com/) to test this solution.
I don't want use the docker stack to understand the construction.

My test API is now created and useable.

[image: api] https://ibb.co/hcjyrJ

Entrypoint: http://api.localhost

My problem is when i will install admin with the [official tutorial](https://api-platform.com/docs/admin/getting-started).

- I don't have any error or warning during installation with yarn

[image: api install] https://ibb.co/gmK1dy

- I have modified the `src/App.js` file with my entrypoint

[image: api js] https://ibb.co/nQKHJy

- I have modify API CORS HTTP Headers to allow the admin's domain to access it. The admin's domain is `http://localhost:3000`

[image: api cors] https://ibb.co/niH7kd

When I try to access to admin : `http://localhost:3000`, I have the message `Unable to retrieve API documentation`.

I don't have any message in console. If I check my network tab, I can view the call to the API with the correct response.

[image: api admin] https://ibb.co/injbdy

If you have any ideas.. I get them all !

Comment: Is this Admin-On-Rest?? I cannot recognize it. Are you sure you tagged correctly????

Comment: As precised, I use [api-platform solution](https://api-platform.com/).
The admin is a part of this solution and using admin-on-rest.

This is decribe on [official tutorial](https://api-platform.com/docs/admin/getting-started)

Comment: Please put code into your question instead of using screenshots.

Answer (score 7):

I've found the solution at this problem.

In `nelmio_cors.yaml`, you must add `Link` in `expose_headers`.

The file must look like as:

```
nelmio_cors:
defaults:
    origin_regex: true
    allow_origin: ['*']
    allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
    allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
    expose_headers: ['Content-Disposition', 'Content-Length', 'Link']
    max_age: 3600
paths:
    '^/': ~
```

Comment: This is almost the only change required to get the Admin component working without Docker. Should be part of documentation imo.

Comment: Why do you need to ask link to the headers?

Comment: still having same problem